# getting issue in json parsing

Tags: php, android, json

i have to download a demo apk. I am inserting some values in database using php. but at some point of time it is throwing an error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  at validity_days of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
```

the code snippet in java:

```
private void upgradeVersion(String apkPath) {   

    System.out.println("SDCARD path checked5:-"+apkPath);
    if(saveUserInfo()==true)
    {
        System.out.println("validity...."+validity);

        if (apkPath != null) {  
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.putExtra("validity_days", validity);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);   
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NetVidya ebook app has been successfully installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }
```

and the php response:

```
{"users":[{"status":"added","installeddate":"","active":"Y","validity_days":""}]}
```

which im getting null here thats y throwing error.

is it possible to handle that exception in android itself? or i have to make some changes in php.

please suggest

Comment: why dont you just use a normal if else method

Comment: Can't see where the variable `validity` is set?

Comment: @droidhot its just a snippet code is so long thats y pasted a snippet only.

Comment: What are you donig with validity_days that is throwin the error I don't actually see any place that you extract this string from the JSON

Comment: Agree with Rarw. It's great to post a snippet but it has to be complete.

Comment: ok you are trying to parse a null string to integer use a try catch and assign 0 value

Comment: @droidhot If you're reckoning the exception somewhere further up is actually NPE, actually better *not* to catch as null check is just 32bit int comparison, exception is branching plus object creation.

Comment: actually it will handle even for some future possible errors that can possibly give a non integer value its just a sugession not an answer

Comment: if `validity` is `int` than try to return in json `"validitiy_days": 0` except empty string.

Comment: @droidhot fair enough point about code being defensive.

Comment: got the issue. its the error in php only from where i am not getting value in response.

Comment: but you're code shouldn't crash just because your server doesn't send a perfect response!

Comment: ok... will correct in android code also.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your JSON parser I'm assuing the issue is becuase you need to use validity_days and that string, at least some of the time, may have no value.

```
try{
    JSONObject fullString = new JSONObject(thatLongStringYouPosted);
    JSONArray users = fullString.getJSONObject("users");
    String validity_days = users.getJSONObject(0),getString("validity_days");
    if(!validity_days.isEmpty() && validity_days != null)            
        //do whatever you want with it
    }
} catch (JSONException e){
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

When parsing JSON you will get back a null value only if what you are looking for does not exist - i.e. there is no "validity_days" string in the response. Otherwise you will just get an empty string. Simply checking for the null and/or the empty string should fix your problem.

Also the try catch block will handle this excpetion within the android code. You can modify your PHP if you want to ensure you always get back a specific value if empty (e.g. you may want to always reuturn a 0 instead of nothing when a field is blank).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Exception you placed above, I think you are getting Exception at this line:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Just replace this line with

```
startActivity(intent);
```

and get JSONString in other activity as

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String str = i.getStringExtra("validity_days");
```

Comment: Why would this throw an exception. All adding the result code does is wait until a result is returned before calling onCreate in the next activity?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you parse your variable `validity_days` to integer before it throws exception..